# Different types of Convergence for a Series Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently investigating the convergence of the following function,

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{k}+\sin(k)}{k^{2}}$

for different "senses". I have shown that $f(x)$ converges uniformly and pointwisely for its domain. All I have left to do is investigate whether it converges in the $L^{p}$ sense. The problem is, I have absolutely no idea what this means! My knowledge on this $L^{p}$ is very minimal and I can not seem to find anything on the www or Rudin. If someone could explain to me what this $L^{p}$ business is it would be greatly appreciated. A few sub-questions I have include:

- How does it differ from uniform convergence?
- Any geometrical interpretations?
- I know that $p\geq1%$. How does every each value of $p$ affect convergence?
- Are there any relationships between each $L^{p}$?

If anyone knows of some nice references to my specific questions, that also would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know what the $L^p$ norm is $\|f\|_p=(\int|f|^pdx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Comment: Ok, thanks @ellya. That is a start to my understanding. Anymore help?

Comment: what does f(x) converge to?

Comment: @ellya. It converges, but I do not to what to. The first term, $\frac{x^{k}}{k{2}}$ converges via the ratio test and letting |x| < 1, and the second term converges via the W-M Test. Are you asking for the function that it converges to? I do not know that. Can you help me find it, perhaps? I have proved Uniform and PW convergence via definition of delta-epsilon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we can see that $|f(x)|=|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}|\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k}{k^2}|+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k}{k^2}|+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Now like you said if we restrict to $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})$ (You'll see why later, then we have $|f(x)|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k}{k^2}|+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k+\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Now as I said $\|f\|_p=(\int |f|^pdx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Let us look at $L^1$, here $\|f\|_1=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}|f(x)|dx=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}dx=(-\ln(1-x)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}x)|_0^1=-\ln{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\ln(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\lt\infty$, so $f\in L^1$.

This is all i've thought up so far, but I hope it helps a bit.

**edit**

I've thought of a much better way to do this.

We as before restrict to $|x|\le 1$, then:

$|f(x)|=|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$

Thus $\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^pdx\leq\int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{\pi^2}{3})^pdx=2(\frac{\pi^2}{3})^p\lt\infty$, Thus $f\in L^p([-1,1])$

Comment: Hey @ellya, yes that has made more sense. A few questions. What you did in the first 4 lines, what did you achieve? Did you show that my original function converges to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{x^k}{k^2}|+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? If so, I can not see why. Sure, I know the function converges, but would not be satisfied to conclude that it converges to that. 

Now, the domain is [-1,1]. And I am curious to know why you only went from 0 -> (1/2).How about L2 and L3 and so on? Thanks !

Comment: Firstly, what I found was an upper bound for f, which allowed me to show that f converges under the $L^1$ norm. I took $(0,1/2)$ literally because it simplifies this integral, Im sure with more effort you can extend the interval. As for L^p in general,  the integral just becomes a bit more complicated, as we take the pth power in the integral.

Comment: I see. With the $L^{p}$ is it possible though? Because I am required to see if it converges in the $L^{p}$ sense. So, how can I come to a final conclusion? Any hint - I don't expect you to do it for me.

Comment: Try what I did, firstly on (0,1/2) BUT do the integral of $|f|^p$ and see what happens,hopefully it will be finite, after that try making the interval larger.

Comment: Also what was the domain of f meant to be? Its not in your post.

Comment: by the ratio test we see that the domain is (-1,1). By testing its endpoint we conclude that the domain is [-1,1].

Comment: I have posted an edit which works a lot nicer

Comment: Your answer is really nice! So sorry to be such a pain, but I would like to clarify that what you have just done, shows that $f(x)$ CONVERGES in the $L^{p}$ sense for all $p>1$, correct? @ellya

Comment: Also, I am confused because I recall you saying that the norm is $(\int |f(x)|^{p}dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. I think you have done a typo though, because the same result should follow.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear, if say $f\in L^p$, that means that $\int |f|^pdx\lt\infty$. Then the norm of $f$ is $\|f\|_p=(\int|f|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. So what I have put is sufficient.

Comment: I see ! So you have just shown me that my function is in all $L^{p}$. Fantastic. How does this connect with whether this function "converges" in this space?

Comment: Just by comparison, since we didn't know what $f$ is, we approximated with a larger sum, which we knew how to evaluate. Now since that sum "converges" in $L^p$, so does $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I really do appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, was a very interesting question, also I though about it some more, and I'm sure the only interval of convergence of the series is $[-1,1]$, anything larger causes the series to diverge, since if $|x|\gt 1$, then for large enough $k$, $|x|^k\gt k^2$, causing the series to diverge.

Comment: I actually still can't prove convergence. Definition of convergence in $L^{p}$ space is $lim \underset{k \to \infty} (\int_{-1}^{1} (\vert f(x)-f_{k}(x) \vert)^{p} dx)^{\frac{1}{p}} = 0$

Comment: thats if we have a sequence of functions, but we dont, we have just one function, and we want to see if it's in $L^p$

Comment: The only way we could have a sequence of functions would be to let $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}$